# Qualifying for Spell Perfection

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, optimization, feat-qualifications

I am currently playing a character that has great use for Spell perfection, but does not have a lot of spare feat slots. I would like to have spell specialization on 2 different spells and perfection on one of them, which are my bread and butter spells. This doesn't leave me with a lot of room for Metamagic feats.

Both spells are from the same school of necromancy. The spells in question are animate dead and create undead, and I would like to retain [Varisian Tatoo](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Varisian%20Tattoo), and [Undead Master](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/undead-master/). The metamagic feats and ability from spell perfection are not of great interest to me, and I am hoping I can find some way to reduce the feat tax through other means. This way I can pick up more team-player feats like craft or flavorful feats like deific boon.

Are there any other ways I could count as having metamagic feats, obtain free/bonus metamagic feats, or qualify for this feat with less than 3 feats? I am currently an archetype wizard that does not get any bonus feats. If I multiclass I do not want to lose many spellcasting abilities. So preferably no more than a level or two, unless it is a prestige class that grants spellcasting levels.

Comment: Are the two spells from the same school, i.e. are we talking about Spell Focus + 2 × Spell Specialization + 2 × Spell Perfection, or 2 × (Spell Focus + Spell Specialization + Spell Perfection)?

Comment: They are both from the same school. Ill add that to the question

Comment: So without bonus feats, you get 10 feats by 19th level: 3 metamagics, Spell Focus, 2 × Spell Specialization, 2 × Spell Perfection, Varisian Tattoo, and Undead Master is 10. So any character can do this by 19th level. A human could do it by 17th, which is notable because that’s the earliest you can have two Spell Perfection feats *anyway* thanks to the 15 ranks of Spellcraft requirement, unless you get Spell Perfection itself as a bonus feat at 15th or 16th. Assuming that isn’t the answer you want, what are you looking for? And are you human?

Comment: I am looking for other ways I could qualify or count as having metamagic feats sooner. I would like to get them by 15/17. And bonus if I dont have to retrain out of craft wondrous, but not required. I am not human, and honestly dont have much use for metamagic feats, as most dont do anything for my main spells anyway. So having a 3 useless feat tax is kinda rough.

Comment: I'm not aware of any possibility to count as having more metamagic feats. But can you give more details on your race/class/build? And what is your ultimate goal: Are you trying to maximize CL? Do you think the Tenebrous Spell or Echoing Spell metamagics might be useful to you?

Comment: What metamagic feat do you want to apply with Spell Perfection? If there's a way to emulate that without actually taking the feat, would that be acceptable? ... or is the "additionally" part (about getting better bonuses) the real bit you're trying to get?

Comment: I guess Tenebrous is useful a fair amount of time. Its not so much the metamagic i want to use from spell perfection, so much as the double feat affects. I am trying to maximize CL. I am a tiefling Undeadmaster Wizard. Going for an ultimate build of being an undead master. Lots of beefy bone shields to frontline for the party.

Comment: You can only take spell perfection once, which of the two spells are you trying to take it on? That could affect the answer.

Comment: Ahhh. That is something I missed. No on in my group caught that and I think we all assumed it could be taken more than once for different spells. I will update my question as I have a chance. Either way, I am still looking for ways to qualify for this without spending 3 feat slots on feats I will not use as often.

Comment: You could ask your GM for leniency, either by allowing useful 3rd-party metamagics (search d20pfsrd for: Spiritual Armaments, Lasting Summons) or by having Sacred Geometry count as having 2 metamagic feats.

Comment: Oooo. Spiritual armaments seems pretty reasonable. Im sure that would only work on undead capable of utilizing weapons and armor in the first place? This would work well with our house-rule of humanoid undead with class levels convert all class HD into racial HD. (Essentially keeping a 10th level ranger skeleton as a 10hd skeleton with no ranger abilities. So I dont have to hunt for monsters to have a skeleton worth a damn. Although monsters are still far better usually with their natural attacks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You'll have to do things the hard way.

Ignoring the fact that you're already an archetyped wizard, [there are no classes or archetypes that grant Spell Perfection as a bonus feat without needing to meet its prerequisites](https://www.aonprd.com/Search.aspx?Query=%22spell%20perfection%22&Filter=111111111111111111&AllTerms=True&OneLine=False&ExcludeAPModule=False&PFSLegalOnly=False). This means that you always need to meet its prerequisites in order to have it.

While class features may grant metamagic feats as bonus feats, you're already an aforementioned archtype wizard, this reduces the way to get metamagic feats to your feats gained normally from leveling, and traits. Since there are no traits that grant metamagic feats (although there are ones that replicate their effects like [Unseen But Not Undone](https://www.aonprd.com/TraitDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Unseen%20but%20Not%20Undone)), this reduces us to feats only.

Since we're trying to reduce the requirement as much as possible, this means we need a feat that counts as two (or more) metamagic feats. Unfortunately, there is no such feat. The closest one to such a thing is [Sacred Geometry](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Sacred%20Geometry), but it doesn't grant you those feats, nor does it even count as a metamagic feat itself, thus it actually wastes a feat you could have otherwise used to qualify for Spell Perfection.

Therefore, the only thing left to do is figure out how to work in enough feats to qualify for it as soon as you can. A sample idea:

| Level | Feat | Misc. Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [Spell Focus](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Spell%20Focus) |  |
| 3 | [Spell Specialization](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Spell%20Specialization) | Use it for [Boneshaker](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=boneshaker) or something at this level, and then set it to animate dead at 4. |
| 5 | [UndeadMaster](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Undead%20Master) | This is the earliest you can gain it, as it requires you to be able to cast [animate dead](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=animate%20dead). Note that it doesn't allow you to **control** more undead created with animate dead, just create more of them. (It does help with [Command Undead](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=command%20undead) though.) |
| 7 | [Reach Spell](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Reach%20Spell) | Animate Undead from a distance or other useful things. |
| 9 | [Spell Specialization](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Spell%20Specialization) | Allows you to create stronger undead with [Create Undead](https://aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=create%20undead) |
| 11 | [Fleeting Spell](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Fleeting%20Spell) | A useful metamagic all around, since none quite really help you with necromancy, this can help you in other areas. |
| 13 | [Thanatopic Spell](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Thanatopic%20Spell) | You've got undead, now you can enervate them (or peopl with death ward). |
| 15 | [Spell Perfection](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Spell%20Perfection) | Note that you need to choose which of your spells you want to apply this boost to, since you can only take it once. |
| 17 | [Varisian Tattoo](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Varisian%20Tattoo) | This is pushed back till later because spell perfection is a boost of 2 caster levels, while this is only a boost of 1. You could take it at 5 and push the metamagic feats (and thus spell perfection) back though. |
| 19 | [Craft Wondrous Item](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Craft%20Wondrous%20Item) | Yeah, it's a bit late, but now you can craft. |

#### A Final Note

You could always try asking your GM to reduce the number of metamagic feats required for spell perfection, or if you can use feats like Undead Master or Sacred Geometry as qualifying feats instead. This would allow you to cut down on the number of feats in your build and give you a bit more breathing room.

#### Potential Dips

Some classes you could dip a level in, in order to receive a metamagic feat as a bonus feat. Note that this would slow you down though.

- Arcanist: [Metamagic Knowledge](https://www.aonprd.com/ArcanistExploits.aspx?ID=15) exploit.
- [Unsworn Shaman](https://www.aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Shaman%20Unsworn%20Shaman): [Secret](https://www.aonprd.com/ShamanHexes.aspx) hex.