# What classes or archetypes grant metamagic feats with a dip?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, metamagic

Inspired by [this comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/191077/qualifying-for-spell-perfection#comment514217_191089), I want to know what other classes/archetypes a player can dip in order to get a metamagic feat as a bonus feat (and if I missed any).

To set the bounds of the list, the list of classes/archetypes should adhere to the following requirements:

- The class should be what grants the bonus feat, although it doesn't have to do so directly.

  - Invalid: Saying that you can take 2 levels in x class and then take a metamagic feat for the feat you get at y level is not valid for us.
  - Valid: Saying that you can take 2 levels of shaman to get a hex for which you can choose the [Secret](https://www.aonprd.com/ShamanHexes.aspx) hex, which grants a metamagic feat, *is* valid.
- Two or less levels required in the class/archetype for the bonus feat. (E.g. 5 levels of vanilla wizard is not a dip for us.) Do note the number of levels required for this.
- The base class and archetypes may all be mentioned. (E.g. Unsworn shaman and shaman both count as answers.)
- Links should be provided to the relevant material, or the sourcebook if the content is not available on the web.
- 3pp is allowed, but it should be noted as such.
- Prestige classes are allowed as a character may incidentally qualify for them on their own. Noting the requirements for the class would be nice, but not necessary.

A starting point for answers has been made as a community wiki post, feel free to add to it or post your own answer.

Comment: One potential option here would be to move your starting list of answers into a Community Wiki answer that can be freely edited and expanded upon by anybody

Comment: @Medix2 true, but I also figured that answerers would like a reward in the form of reputation. I think I will do that though, it's not like they're required to edit it or anything.

Comment: Otherwise it would have to be closed because there would be no way to distinguish whether Answer A with 5 options and Answer B with 4 non-overlapping options or Answer C that copy-pasted A and B and added one... (unless that guidance has changed with the use of community wiki answers)

Comment: @Ifusaso Questions answered by lists are currently considered on-topic, and it's fine to have answers with no possible means of distinguishing which is better. We have quite a few cases of this; I've been debating posting a Meta about them (and have a massive list of them) but have decided that just using CW answers works extremely well

Answer (score 2):

### 1 Level:

- Arcanist (1 level): [Metamagic Knowledge](https://www.aonprd.com/ArcanistExploits.aspx?ID=15) exploit.
- [Exploiter Wizard](https://www.aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Wizard%20Exploiter%20Wizard) (1 level): [Metamagic Knowledge](https://www.aonprd.com/ArcanistExploits.aspx?ID=15) exploit.
- [Unsworn Shaman](https://www.aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Shaman%20Unsworn%20Shaman) (1 level): [Secret](https://www.aonprd.com/ShamanHexes.aspx) hex.
- [Loremaster](https://aonprd.com/PrestigeClassesDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Loremaster) (1 level): Secret (Applicable Knowledge) (see class features). Prestige class, maintains spellcasting progression. Requires feats and skill ranks.

### 2 Levels:

- [Shaman](https://aonprd.com/ClassDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Shaman) (2 levels): [Secret](https://www.aonprd.com/ShamanHexes.aspx) hex.